# Dispose SpringClientFactory's ApplicationContext for Ribbon Client

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

In spring-cloud, when Zuul is set to scan all the services registered in Eureka, am I right to say that it creates a load-balancer context dynamically for each serviceId/vipAddress/virtualHostname?

When this load-balancer-context will be disposed (safely)? 
Is it when all the instances of a service gets de-registered from Eureka ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ApplicationContext`'s created by `SpringClientFactory` are closed when the `SpringClientFactory.destroy()` lifecycle method is called.

Comment: So the context for a service will be alive, even if there is no instances of that service in Eureka ?